# Cons box implementation

Tags: ruby, scheme

I cannot seem to figure out a way to do Scheme's cons boxes in Ruby (it seems its pretty much all arrays). This is a pretty rough outline:

```
class cons
    def initialize (car, cdr)
    @car = car
    @cdr = cdr
    end

    #return the car of the pair
    def car
        return @car
    end

    #return the cdr of the pair
    def cdr
        return @cdr
    end
end
```

I can pass two values and call the `car` and `cdr`, but this is not a list of any sort (just two values). How do I make a list on which I can insert something as in Scheme cons:

```
myCons = (cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, cons(4, 5)))))
```

The closest I can find is making my own array like `myArray = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and then using `puts myArray.join(' ')`. This only gives me `"1 2 3 4 5"` and not `(1 2 3 4 5)` though, and that's not taking into account I still can't actually build the array with cons, I simply made it myself.

Comment: Before you try to implement anything, you should at least learn the basics of Ruby syntax. `Class cons` is not valid in Ruby.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Ruby. It appears you simply don't understand how cons lists work. Maybe you should ask a question about that?

Comment: A cons cell is just a structure with two fields.  That's enough structure to implement a singly-linked-list, and in Lisp, the convention is that a list is either the symbol `nil` (the empty list, also written as `()`) or a cons cell where the `car` of the cell is the first element of the list and the `cdr` is the *rest* of the list (i.e., `nil` or another list).  That's all.  In Lisps, it's convenient to *print* this in a special way, but that's just for show.

Comment: See [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433) and [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433) for a bit more about these conventions and what `cons`, `car`, and `cdr` have to do.  The previous comment says that cons cells are structures with two fields, but that's more than what's guaranteed.  E.g., you could do it just with lexical closures, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1391892/1281433) to [What is the Definition of a Lisp Cons Cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1317023/1281433).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Exactly. See my implementation of the `Cons` class, which does implement the dotted notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of `Cons` that has a decent print syntax built-in (including support for improper lists), and is enumerable:

```
class Cons
  include Enumerable
  attr_accessor :car, :cdr

  class << self
    alias [] new
  end

  def initialize(car, cdr)
    self.car = car
    self.cdr = cdr
  end

  def each_pair
    return to_enum(:each_pair) unless block_given?
    cell = self
    while cell.is_a? Cons
      yield cell.car, cell.cdr
      cell = cell.cdr
    end
  end

  def each
    return to_enum unless block_given?
    each_pair { |car,| yield car }
  end

  def print
    sb = '('
    each_pair do |car, cdr|
      sb << yield(car)
      case cdr
      when Cons
        sb << ' '
      when nil
      else
        sb << ' . ' << yield(cdr)
      end
    end
    sb << ')'
  end

  def to_s
    print &:to_s
  end

  def inspect
    print &:inspect
  end
end
```

Oh, and here's an easy way to create a list (similar to the `list` function found in both Common Lisp and Scheme):

```
def list(*items)
  items.reverse_each.reduce(nil) { |result, item| Cons[item, result] }
end
```

Examples:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = Cons[1, Cons[2, Cons[3, nil]]]
=> (1 2 3)
irb(main):002:0> b = Cons[1, Cons[2, Cons[3, 4]]]
=> (1 2 3 . 4)
irb(main):003:0> a.to_a
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):004:0> a.map(&Math.method(:sqrt))
=> [1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772]
irb(main):005:0> list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
=> (1 2 3 4 5)
```

---

Update: A user wrote me asking how to (among other things) append cons-based lists. As a Schemer, I like to treat cons cells as immutable, so the standard approach for appending is to cons each element, right-to-left, from the left-hand list onto the right-hand list. Here's how I would implement it.

First, let's define a `reduce_right` method. (Technically, this is a right *fold*, not a right *reduce*, but Ruby prefers the term "reduce" rather than "fold", so that's what I'll use here.) We'll reopen both `NilClass` and `Cons` to make this work:

```
class NilClass
  def reduce_right(init)
    init
  end
end

class Cons
  def reduce_right(init, &block)
    block.call(cdr.reduce_right(init, &block), car)
  end
end
```

Then, `append` is as simple as using `reduce_right`:

```
def append(lhs, rhs)
  lhs.reduce_right(rhs) { |result, item| Cons[item, result] }
end
```

This allows you to append two lists, but usually, it's more handy to allow appending any number of lists (and this is what Scheme's `append` allows):

```
def append(*lists)
  lists.reverse_each.reduce do |result, list|
    list.reduce_right(result) { |cur, item| Cons[item, cur] }
  end
end
```

Notice that in both cases, the rightmost "list" is not required to be a proper list, and you can create improper lists by putting something that's not a cons cell there:

```
irb(main):001:0> append(list(1, 2, 3), list(4, 5))
=> (1 2 3 4 5)
irb(main):002:0> append(list(1, 2, 3), list(4, 5), 6)
=> (1 2 3 4 5 . 6)
irb(main):003:0> append(list(1, 2, 3), list(4, 5), list(6))
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

(Non-rightmost lists must be proper lists.)

Comment: This works perfectly. Could you please elaborate what the print &:to_s does? For example, just putting the code from print into to_s will not work. What does &:to_s accomplish? (As I said I am new and would like to actually understand what is happening).

Comment: Sure, `&:to_s` is a shorthand for `{ |x| x.to_s }`, and similarly `&:inspect` is a shorthand for `{ |x| x.inspect }` (see [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) for more details). These blocks get invoked by the `yield`s inside the `print` method. The reason I did this was that I wanted to implement both `to_s` and `inspect` without tons of duplicate code.

Comment: If we passed in `&:to_s`, then `yield(car)` is the same as `car.to_s`, and `yield(cdr)` is the same as `cdr.to_s`. Likewise, if we passed in `&:inspect`, then we get `car.inspect` and `cdr.inspect`.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a method (`to_a`) which will build your array:

```
class Cons

  def initialize(car, cdr)
    @car = car
    @cdr = cdr
  end

  attr_reader :car, :cdr

  def to_a
    list = cdr.respond_to?(:to_a) ? cdr.to_a : cdr
    [car, *list]
  end
end

myCons = Cons.new(1, Cons.new(2, Cons.new(3, Cons.new(4,5))))
myCons.to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This method checks if `cdr` supports `to_a` itself, and calls it if possible, then it adds `car` to the beginning of the list, and returns the created list.

If you want to have a syntax similar to `cons(1, cons(2,...)` you can do it using `[]`:

```
class Cons
  def self.[](car, cdr)
    Cons.new(car, cdr)
  end
end
```

Now you can write:

```
myCons = Cons[1, Cons[2, Cons[3, Cons[4,5]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a more curious approach from SICP :)

```
def cons(a, b)
    lambda { |seek|
        seek == 0 ? a : b
    }
end

def car(pair)
    pair.call(0)
end

def cdr(pair)
    pair.call(1)
end
```